# Python/LXML - Getting "grandchildren" from etree

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, elementtree

Here is a sample of the XML tree I am traversing:

```
<entry dataset="Swiss-Prot" created="1993-07-01+01:00" modified="2013-04-03+01:00" version="144">
  <accession>P31750</accession>
  <accession>Q62274</accession>
  <accession>Q6GSA6</accession>
  <name>AKT1_MOUSE</name>
  <protein>
    <recommendedName>
      <fullName>RAC-alpha serine/threonine-protein kinase</fullName>
      <ecNumber>2.7.11.1</ecNumber>
    </recommendedName>
    <alternativeName>
      <fullName>AKT1 kinase</fullName>
    </alternativeName><alternativeName>
      <fullName>Protein kinase B</fullName>
     ..........
```

I am trying to get to `recommendedName`, and here is the current `Python` code I am using to reach it:

```
protein = e.find("{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}protein")
r_names = []
for child in protein.find("recommendedName"):
     for subchild in child.find("fullName"):
          r_names.append(subchild.text)
```

`e` in this context represent from `<entry>` to `</entry>`. When I try to run this code, I get the following error from the Python interpreter:

```
for child in protein.find("recommendedName"):
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

So it is telling me that `child` here is not an iterable object. I dont really get that, because `protein` is definitely iterable, so if it `finds` something it should be iterable. At any rate, how would I use the `lxml` API to reach the grandchild nodes `recommendedName` and `alternativeName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for child in protein.find("recommendedName"):
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The error message is saying that `protein.find` is returning `None`. So no `recommendedName` elements were found.

Since you are using a namespace to find `protein`, you probably need to use

```
for child in protein.find("{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}recommendedName")
```

or better yet,

```
for child in protein.xpath("uniprot:recommendedName",
                           namespaces = dict(uniprot='http://uniprot.org/uniprot'))
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot, for some reason I thought I only needed the namespace for the root, its children, and their siblings. I didnt realize I could use it for nested elements as well.